# Any closed orientable $3$-manifold admits a Heegaard splitting

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Textbook: Lectures on the topology of 3-manifolds by Nikolai Saveliev

> Theorem. *Any closed orientable 3-manifold admits a Heegaard splitting.*
> *Proof.* Let $T$ be a triangulation of a closed orientable $3$-manifold $M$. We associate with $T$ a Heegaard splitting of $M$ as follows. Let us replace each vertex of $T$ by a ball, each edge by a cylinder, each side of a tetrahedron by a plate, and each tetrahedron by a ball. The union $H(T)$ of the vertex balls and the cylinders is a handlebody, and so is the union $H'(T)$ of the tetrahedron balls and plates. Therefore, $M = H(T)\cup H'(T)$ is a Heegaard splitting of the manifold $M$.

If I understand correctly, $H(T)$ and $H'(T)$ are like dual graphs in planar graphs. I convinced myself $H(T)$ and $H'(T)$ are handlebodies (up to homeomorphism) but I can't see why two handlebodies have the same genus. Could you explan why?

Comment: They have the same surface, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Why?

Comment: You are asking a wrong question. Saveliev is sloppy defining handlebodies and he does not prove that they have disjoint interiors and their union is the entire $M$. For a real proof see Hempel's book, theorem 2.5.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you for the appropriate reference for 3-manifolds!

Comment: Hempel gives you a very precise description of the handlebodies (using the 2nd barycentric subdivision). He leaves it as an exercise to prove that $H_1\cup H_2=M$ and $H_1\cap H_2=\partial H_1=\partial H_2$, which is a good exercise to work out: You have to prove this for a general 3-simplex. Once this is done, the equality of genera is clear since the genus of a handlebody is the genus of its boundary and boundaries are the same for $H_1, H_2$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Now I see they are indeed the same surface!